# Vertical circular motion when string slacks

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, string

When a particle leaves vertical circular motion after slacking. Is it possible the body at the end of string will move to the centre and can we calculate that intial velocity in a parabolic motion as well as intial velocity in which the ball is thrown at the starting?
Given centre coordinates (a, b)

Comment: Duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/782744/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When string slacks in circular motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/782744/)